# ¿Cómo enviar imagen por ajax para agregarla a la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, imagen

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual requiero  agregar una imagen a la base de datos `MySQL` mediante `Ajax`.

Una de las primeras dudas con las que me he topado es que en algunos tutoriales utilizan la función `serialize()` para obtener los datos de un `<form>`. Mi duda es si se puede obtener el archivo y enviarlo mediante `JSON`.

**Código**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-5">
            <label>Nombre del Partido Político</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="txtNombrePartido" placeholder="PRI, PAN, PRD, Etc.." class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Cargar Imagen</label>
                <label for=""> (<small>Archivos Soportados <code>.JPG</code>, <code>JPGE</code> y<code>.PNG</code></small>)</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileImage" name="fileImage" accept=".jpg,jpge,.png,.ico">
            </div>                                                              
        </div>                                                  
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                <button id="btnNPAceptar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
function nuevoPartido(partido,imagen){
$.ajax({
    url: '../../../../control/consultas/comparacionesAjax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Partido: partido, Imagen: imagen, Funcion: "NuevoPartido" },
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});

}
```

¿Cómo enviar imagen por ajax para agregarla a la base de datos?